# String and function object

Tags: c++

I encountered this issue, but I'm not sure what to make of it...

```
class Goo
{
    char _ch;
    string _str;
public:
    function<void(void)> dobedo;

    // Constructor 1
    Goo(string s) : _str(s)
    {   
        cout << "Constructed: [" << &_str << "]: " << _str << endl;
        dobedo = [&]()
        {
            cout << "Dobedo: [" << &_str << "]: "<< _str << endl;
        };
    }
    // Constructor 2
    Goo(char ch) : _ch(ch)
    {
        dobedo = [&]() {
            cout << "Dobedo: " << _ch << endl;
        };
    }
    void show() { cout << "Show: [" << &_str << "]: " << _str << endl; }
};


int main()
{
    string myStr1("ABCD");
    string myStr2("EFGH");
    vector<Goo> goos;

    goos.push_back(Goo(myStr1));
    goos.push_back(Goo(myStr2));

    goos[0].dobedo();
    goos[1].dobedo();

    goos[0].show();
    goos[1].show();

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, the function object wasn't able to print _str, despite being able to locate the memory address:

```
Constructed: [00EFF80C]: ABCD
Constructed: [00EFF7B0]: EFGH
Dobedo: [00EFF80C]:
Dobedo: [00EFF7B0]:
Show: [032F2924]: ABCD
Show: [032F296C]: EFGH
```

I did not have any problems with char variables though.

```
int main()
{
    vector<Goo> goos;

    goos.push_back(Goo('#'));
    goos.push_back(Goo('%'));

    goos[0].dobedo();
    goos[1].dobedo();

    return 0;
}
```

The output gives:

```
Dobedo: #
Dobedo: %
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour in your code without defining copy constructor. Default copy constructor copies all members by value. So your lambda object is copied and it holds references to destroyed object - `_str` (when vector had to be reallocated while calling `push_back` method).

Define copy constructor and move constructor for `Goo` class:

```
Goo(const Goo& g)
{
    _str = g._str;
    dobedo = [&]()
    {
        cout << "Dobedo: [" << &_str << "]: "<< _str << endl;
    };
}

Goo(Goo&& g)
{
    _str = move(g._str);
    dobedo = [&]()
    {
        cout << "Dobedo: [" << &_str << "]: "<< _str << endl;
    };
}
```

Comment: You should also define copy/move assignment operators + destructor to follow the Rule of Five.

Comment: note: a copy constructor is invoked whenever a `Goo` is `push_back`ed into `goos`.

Comment: @YSC unless you use the T&& overload. Then it's the move constructor that is invoked.

Comment: After all of these you think.. Maybe it would be better instead of all to capture a _copy_ of string ;)?

Answer (score 1):

Your output clearly shows that the address of `_str` in constructor isn't the same as one in `show`. It means that your object was copied/moved. It may happen while it is pushed to a vector. BTW, it also may take place when you push/pop other elements to/from a vector as vector doesn't guarantee elements to stay at the same memory address.

When you create `dobedo` functor, all captured fields are copied to it. In the first case it was the address of `_str` which becomes invalid when the object is copied/moved (nobody updates it upon a move/copy!). Occasionally we may find an empty-string like stuff at that address (although accessing it is now a memory violation). In the second case, a character is captured and stored - and it definitely remains valid upon any object location change.